# configure gnuplot to handle timeseries like excel

Tags: linux, excel, math, graph, gnuplot

I am trying to graph events over time with gnuplot. Excel's default behavior produces a more readable graph.

I would like my graph from gnuplot to look like Excel's.

```
set terminal png size 1200,800
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"
set output "graph.png"
set xrange ["2015-02-01_08-54":"2015-02-01_23-20"]
set yrange [0:70]
set grid
set xlabel "24-Hour"
set ylabel "Events"
set title "Events"
plot "events.dat" using 1:2 index 0 title "events" with filledcurves ls 1
```

I've spent many hours manipulating source data and plot.conf, but **it's not clear to me what Excel is doing differently.**

Gnuplot Output:

[image: gnuplot output]

Excel Output:

[image: Excel output]

Comment: Dataset: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AcdC3EEG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel plots with a wrong x-scale: it ignores the time values, and puts the values given in the first column at equidistant x-values as labels.

To get the same behavior with gnuplot, you must use `xticlabel` to place the values in the first column as tic labels, and use the row number (column 0) as x-values:

```
set xtics rotate by 90 right noenhanced
plot "events.dat" using 0:2:xticlabel(1) title "events" with filledcurves
```

Now, this would give you rather unreadable labels, because that are too many. With some tweaks you get a nicer result:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1200,800
set output "graph.png"
set yrange [0:70]
set grid y
set xlabel "24-Hour"
set ylabel "Events"
set xtics out nomirror scale 0.5 rotate by 90 right font ',8' noenhanced
plot "events.dat" using 0:2:xticlabel(int($0) % 5 == 0 ? strcol(1) : '') title "events" with filledcurves
```

[image]

**Disclaimer:** Please use this script only to understand what Excel does and not to reproduce it, because it gives a very wrong impression of the actual time spans in which your events happen!